# Volume integral and cube

Tags: calculus

I need to calculate the surface integral of $v = (2xz, x+2, y(z-3))$ around a cube [image]

But i am getting the wrong answer, i am not sure why:

> The integral around ii is zero
>
> The integral around iii = - integral around iv
>
> Around v : 4
>
> Around i : 16
>
> Around vi : -12

Now, i am getting the answer 8, while the book is getting 32. Apparently, they are adding 12 instead of subtract it of. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face ${\tt vi}$ we use $x$, $y$ as parameters and then  have $$ {\bf v}(x,y)=(0,x+2,-3y),\qquad{\bf n}=(0,0,-1),\qquad {\rm d}\omega={\rm d}(x,y)\ .$$
It follows that
$$\int_{\tt vi}{\bf v}\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega=\int_{[0,2]^2}3y\>{\rm d}(x,y)=6\int_0^2 y\>dy=12\ .$$
Your mistake comes from the fact that $x$, $y$ in this order a priori produce the wrong orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in surface (v) and (vi). The signs are reversed.

For surface (v), $z = 2$ and *outward* normal vector is $(0, 0, 1)$

$\vec V = (2xz, x+2, y(z-3))$

$\vec V \cdot (0, 0, 1) = - y$

Similarly for surface (vi),

$z = 0$ and *outward* normal vector is $(0, 0, -1)$

$\vec V \cdot (0, 0, -1) = 3 y$

So net flux through surface (v) and (vi) is

$\displaystyle \int_0^2 \int_0^2 2 y \ dx \ dy = 8$

So total flux through all six surfaces of the cube is $16 + 8 = 24$.

Applying divergence theorem confirms it -

$\nabla \cdot \vec{V} = 2z + y$

So, $I = \displaystyle \int_0^2 \int_0^2 \int_0^2 (y+2z) \ dx \ dy \ dz = 24$